# Mac terminal ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, macos, google-app-engine, terminal, localhost

I am following this tutorial to setup a Wordpress website on Google cloud:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

- I am working on a Mac with OSX 10.10.3.
- I have installed the PHP SDK for Google App Engine software.

Now I am trying to install MySQL server on my mac. I have downloaded the Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

As the tutorial says, I am command the following line in my Terminal:

```
/Users/myuser/Downloads/mysql-5.6.24-osx10.9-x86_64/bin/mysql/mysql -u root -p mypassword
```

First the terminal asked for my password, and when I enter this the following error occurs:

**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)**

Comment: This occurred for me after restoring a new Mac Mini from a Time Machine backup. I had to uninstall mysql@5.7 and reinstall it for it to start working. Bit a hammer but was relatively painless since all my configurations were retained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common error , you can fix it like this

[image]

You can remove root password with this command sequence:

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done the 2 lines. But I still get the error.. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Did you reboot MySQL?

Comment: try this: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

Comment: I did a reboot by: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart. But now I get ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) if I try to install mysql

Comment: but if you are not a command line guy if you go to your mac settings you must have mysql configs right there

Comment: that's because you set a password for root user.. I edited my initial post to add information about how you remove the password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77192/discussion-between-robbert-and-diogo-cunha).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I got it working with a minor fix. I'm using MAC + MAMP PRO, so my .sock file is somewhere else. This is the correct solution for me: ```sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock```

Answer (score 29):

Looks like Mysql server has not started.

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Had exactly the same issue, used the above command to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I installed Valet+ and it stopped server, had to start manually, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8):

`OSX 10.13.2 High Sierra`
`mariadb 10.2.12`

I got the exact same error when I tried to use `mariadb`, which I installed with homebrew.  The first thing I did after installing was:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through 
socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

To troubleshoot, I did:

```
~$ which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

and then I tried:

```
~$ mysql -u 7stud -p test
 Enter password:
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server 
 through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

and:

```
~$ mysql -u -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server 
through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

**The solution**:

```
~$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.180127 00:24:48 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/MyMBP.home.err'.
180127 00:24:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
 SUCCESS! 

~$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 5.5.5-10.2.12-MariaDB Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Okay, let's go:

```
mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE my_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use my_db;
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE people (
    -> id INT(12) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    -> name VARCHAR(40), 
    -> info VARCHAR(100)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> describe people;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| info  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO people(name, info) VALUES("Joe", "a b c") ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from people;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | info  |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | Joe  | a b c |
+----+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO people(name, info) VALUES("Beth", "1 2 3") ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from people;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | info  |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | Joe   | a b c |
|  2 | Beth  | 1 2 3 |
+----+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye

~$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MySQL
. SUCCESS! 
~$
```

The best instructions I found for manually starting and stopping mariadb are paradoxically at [Starting and Stopping MariaDB Automatically](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/starting-and-stopping-mariadb-automatically/):

> You have the option of starting the mysqld server several different
>   ways:
>
> 1. Run or invoke mysqld itself. An example of doing this is described more in Running MariaDB from the Source Directory.
> 2. Use the mysqld_safe startup script
> 3. Use the mysql.server startup script
>
> The mysql.server script starts mysqld by first changing to the MariaDB
>   install directory and then calling mysqld_safe. Adding an appropriate
>   user line to the [mysqld] group in your my.cnf file will cause the
>   server to be run as that user.
>
> If you have installed MariaDB to a non-standard location, you may need
>   to edit the mysql.server script to get it to work right.
>
> mysql.server works as a standard SysV-style init script. As such you
>   use the script with start and stop arguments like so:
>
> ```
> mysql.server start
> mysql.server stop
> ```

Comment: After going through 100 places, I came to the right place. In my case I have maria db and mamp both but they keep on conflicting each other, when I follow the way you have written above my *mysql* doesn't appear to be connected in CLI neither in Sql workbench. Can you please help me what's the issue? It keeps on using maria db and my core mysql works in websites but I cannot access in CLI.

Comment: @Umar, 1) What do you get for `$ which mysql.server`?  2) What do you get for `$ which mysql`?  3) What do you get for `~$ ruby -e 'puts ENV["PATH"].split ":"'` ?

Comment: I was having error that says the directory is not empty. I realized that my mysql file path is: `/usr/local/OPT/mysql@5.7/` by writing `$ which mysql`  Thank you so much for this tip! I had been trying to fix it for 2 days.

Answer (score 6):

The error:
`Mac terminal ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

How I solved this on my MAC + MAMP (pro) setup:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`

> Which creates a symlink from /tmp/mysql.sock to the MAMP mysql.sock

Now restart MAMP and then the error should not occur again.

Comment: For XAMP use 
`sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 6):

Before doing anything drastic, try connecting using the loopback address `127.0.0.1` instead of the default `localhost`.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

The name `localhost`, which would be used by default if you don't specify `-h`, connects over named pipes rather than TCP/IP. This is the error message you see if named pipes are not enabled.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed Mysql through Homebrew, just run below command, that will be helpful.

> brew services start mysql

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew will not start the mysql server once it is installed and hence you get the error.

```
$ brew services list
Name  Status  User Plist
mysql stopped

$ mysql -u root
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
 '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

$ mysql -uroot
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
 '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

You just need to start the mysql service and then connect.

```
$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!

$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.19 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you experienced this issue on MacOSX Catalina after having downgraded from MySQL8 to MySQL5.7 via Homebrew, I managed to fix it with:

*WARNING: Back up any databases before proceeding with the commands below*

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
brew postinstall mysql@5.7 -v
mysqld
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to switch the version of the mysql.

Below is the instruction for using HomeBrew on Mac.

First list all the versions of mysql:

```
$ brew list --versions mysql
```

Switch to an older version:

```
$ brew services stop mysql
$ brew switch mysql 5.7.20
$ brew services start mysql
```

Comment: I had the same problem when upgrading to mysql 8.*

Answer (score 1):

This work for me, just delete the file  `$ rm /tmp/mysql.sock`
then `$ brew services mariadb restart`

Comment: I tried your solution but did not work. Here is what I did to make it work. `brew services start mariadb`

Answer (score -1):

yes it works for me too....
but I don't understand : in both of php.ini files conf (apache and php of MAMP) path of socket is good : `socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`
so why still looking for `/tmp/mysql.sock` ???

Thank's for everyone who can "eclairer ma lanterne !"

Comment: How does this answer the question?